# Inserting an image by coordinates

Tags: java, spring, backend

Can I somehow insert an image by coordinates into another image?

A MultipartFile comes to me with an image, if its aspect ratio != 16:9, then I generate a new image with that aspect ratio and black and in the middle of it I need to insert the image that came to me.

At the moment I can only generate a black image, but I have no way to figure out how to insert the image by coordinates into another image.
I tried using Graphics2D.drawImage(), but it didn't work for me.

```
`public static String getImageAndReturnPathToResult(MultipartFile multipartFile){
    try{
> //Image taken from the front
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(multipartFile.getInputStream()); 

> //Generating a new black image
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(1920, 1080, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
        g2d.dispose();
        
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "error";
}`
```

Comment: try this sample... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you failed with Graphics2D.drawImage() because you didn't pass the arguments correctly. Try:

```
Graphics2D.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
Graphics2D.dispose();
```

After that everything should work.